# chrome extension: sending data from popup to unlink js file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

im messing around with chrome extensions.
i got a litell form i did in the `popup html`, and im trying to do somthing with a user input.
i got a file that is linked in the `popup.html`, that hold this function:

```
function click(e) {
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    file: "theJs.js"
});
```

}

now in the file `theJs.js`, i write the code i want to be executed on the current tab that is running(can get and set info on the current tab).

so my qustion is:

how do i get a info from the `popup.html`, and send it to `theJs.js` file,
so i can use the user input on the current tab?

is it possible?

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [message passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html)

content.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.type == 'apply') {
        applySettings(request.settings);
        sendResponse();
    }
});
```

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, { type: "apply", name: name, settings: settings },
        function(response) {
            showMessage('success', '<strong>' + name + '</strong> applied.');
        }
    );
});
```

- [My Extension: user-bootstrap#popup.html](https://github.com/greatghoul/user-bootstrap/blob/master/popup.html#L86)
- [My Extension: user-bootstrap#content.js](https://github.com/greatghoul/user-bootstrap/blob/master/content.js#L1)